# Free professional development software

Tags: visual-studio, language-agnostic

I've just stumbled on a [Microsoft program](https://www.dreamspark.com/) that offers Visual Studio Professional, among other things like SQL Server and Windows Server 2008, for free (as in beer). The catch is that you have to be a student.

Anyone know any other places where you can acquire software like this for free - legally that is.

Comment: You say that having an .edu email is enough. I would check the licence agreement - as if it specifically indicates that you have to be a student then you are breaking the agreement and IMO stealing. Also I would check the agreement to see how you are allowed to use the software - i'm sure there are limitations on what you can do. i.e you can't make profit or can only use the software for school work. We had free copies of Windows at University with those restrictions.

Comment: You are correct, it is not for commercial purposes.

Comment: you don't specify the language you want to deal with. For example, for C++ there are a lot of free excellent IDEs. Eclipse, for example.

Comment: @rursw1 I work mostly with .NET but I wasn't thinking of a particular language. Perhaps this would be better as a community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not free per se, but with Microsoft's BizSpark programme, you can get an MSDN (which includes all of their operating systems and development tools, and most of their office software) if you own a private company that is turning over less than $1,000,000 and less than 3 years old.

I think you have to pay $100 when the 3 year programme comes to an end.

http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) and SQL Server Express are free for anyone.

Unfortunately there's no Windows 7 Express :(

Comment: and so is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express......

Answer (score 2):

If youre the lucky owner or is somehow involved in a small company, the Microsoft [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) programme is excellent. 3 years of free use of practically all MS software.

Comment: That's awesome for any new business!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as that would cripple their business model. Free is an invitation that will get people to use that when they're learning, and hope to force them to use the software later, but paid.

There are, as suggested by Radu, a number of equally good, but different, alternatives (Eclipse, Code::Blocks, Netbeans, QtCreator).

You can use the Visual Studio compilers and tools through the Windows SDK, but that won't provide you with the IDE.

Comment: Express is free. DreamSpark makes the full products free to students. BizSpark makes the full products free to startups. Free forever, no, but free while you get started, absolutely.

Comment: Did know about Dreamspark, but did not know about BizSpark. Now I do :)